# Trying to make a maze

Tags: python

Hi I am learning Python from the week, and I got the idea to make maze in python.  After a long time trying to do this, I always came to this starting point:

[image]

I would like to get the effect of what is on the 2 selection

My code:

```
def make(x):
    if x%2 !=0:
        return False
    else:
        table = []
        for i in range(0,x):
            if i == 0:
                table.append([0]*x)
            elif i == x-1:
                table.append([0]*x)
                return table
            else:
                if i == 1:
                    table.append([0])
                    table[i].extend([1]*(x-2))
                    table[i].extend([0])
                elif i==x-2:
                    table.append([0])
                    table[i].extend([1]*(x-2))
                    table[i].extend([0])
                else:
                    table.append([0]*(x))       

for j in make(20):
    print j
```

Comment: What is the question? Does your code work?

Comment: Humm, as I can see, the provided source code is creating and displaying the effect of the selection 1. So, I suppose that you want to modify your algorithm to obtain the effect of the selection 2. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It's generic enough for any value of x that satisfies `x%2==0`:

```
def make(x):
    if x%2 != 0:
       return False
    else:
       table = []
       for i in range(0,x):
         if i>=x/2:
            fac, rem = divmod(x-i-1,2)
         else:
            fac, rem = divmod(i,2)
         table.append([0,1]*(fac+rem))
         table[i].extend([rem]*(x-4*(fac+rem)))
         table[i].extend([1,0]*(fac+rem))
       return table
```

Probably better form to raise an exception instead of returning false but I don't know the larger context of what this fits into so I'll just leave it as is.

Or using the same approach as above you can split the single loop into two loops with a separate function like this:

```
def makeRow(x,fac,rem):
    row=[0,1]*(fac+rem)
    row.extend([rem]*(x-4*(fac+rem)))
    row.extend([1,0]*(fac+rem))
    return row

def make2(x):
    if x%2 != 0:
       return False
    else:
       table = []
       for i in range(0,int(x/2)):
          table.append(makeRow(x,*divmod(i,2)))
       for i in range(int(x/2),x):
          table.append(makeRow(x,*divmod(x-i-1,2)))
       return table
```

Or if you prefer to turn the above into something more pythonic:

```
def make3(x):
    if x%2 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        table=[makeRow(x,*divmod(i,2)) for i in range(0,int(x/2))]
        table.extend([makeRow(x,*divmod(x-i-1,2)) for i in range(int(x/2),x)])
        return table
```

Answer (score 0):

Why point out the error "table [i + j]. extend ([int (j% 2)] * (x-(4 * s))) IndexError: list index out of range" and whether in general has the right to work

```
def fun(x):
table=[]
s=0
for i in range(0,int(x/2)):
    if i ==0:
        table.append([0]*x)
    else:
        if i==((x/2)-1):
            table.append([0,1]*(x/4))
            table[i].extend([1,0]*(x/4))
        elif i==(x/2):
            table.append([0,1]*(x/4))
            table[i].extend([1,0]*(x/4))
        elif i == (x/2-1):
            table.append([0]*x)
            return table
        else:
            if i<(((x/2)/2)-2):
                    s+=1
                    for j in range(0,2):    
                        table.append([0,1]*s)
                        table[i+j].extend([int(j%2)]*(x-(4*s)))
                        table[i+j].extend([1,0]*s)


            if i>((x/2)/2):
                for j in range(0,2):    
                    if len(table) == (x-2):
                        break
                    else:
                        table.append([0,1]*s)
                        table[i+j].extend([int(j%2)]*(x-(4*s)))
                        table[i+j].extend([1,0]*s)
                s-=1
```

for j in fun(20):
    print j